# What style/font is this?

Tags: fonts, numbering, theorems, drop-cap

Does anyone know how to create numbering for Theorem/lemma/… like this one in the image below, also any idea about the font name?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: See [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://goo.gl/YsWvA)

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? Do you want to automate the creation of theorem environments with drop cap numbers?

Comment: @hpesoj626  Yes,this is my target.

Comment: I added an answer using the ntheorem package to create theorems with drop cap numbers.

Comment: The font is Palatino from Hermann Zapf or a clone of it. You can get it via package `mathpazo` or `tgpagella`. When using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you could also load "Palatino Linotype" (ships with Windows), "TeX Gyre Pagella", "FPL Neu", just to name a few.

Comment: NB : this is from http://publications.rwth-aachen.de/record/50390/files/Ensenbach_Marc.pdf#page=20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Remarks**

I reproduced Heiko's answer using `ntheorem`. There is a tricky thing about it: You can't wrap the `\lettrine` into the `[]` of the `\item` as one would normally do for theorems. I get the error

```
! Argument of \@lettrine has an extra }.
```

if I do this. I don't know why, maybe somebody knows (Please comment).

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\definecolor{theoremgray}{gray}{.5}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}%
    {\item[]\theorem@headerfont \lettrine[loversize=.11,findent=0.5em,nindent=0pt]{\textcolor{theoremgray}{##2}}{\textls{##1\theorem@separator}} }%
    {\item[]\theorem@headerfont \lettrine[loversize=.11,findent=0.5em,nindent=0pt]{\textcolor{theoremgray}{##2}}{\textls{##3\theorem@separator}} }
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\setlength{\textwidth}{.85\textwidth}% just for reproducing the example
\begin{document}
\section{Sectiontitle}
\subsection{Subsectiontitle}
\begin{theorem}[Bezeichnungen]
    Ist $G$ eine (multiplikativ geschriebene) Gruppe, so f"uhrt man
    f"ur beliebige $g \in G$ und $M, N \subseteq G$ die Bezeichnungen
    \begin{alignat*}{4}
      &Mg &&= \{mg &&\mid m &&\in M\},\\
      &gN &&= \{gn &&\mid n &&\in N\},\\
      &MN &&= \{mn &&\mid m &&\in M, n \in N\}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image: theorem]

Comment: thanks for this code. I noticed a conflict with the package amsthm. for example try to use \begin{proof} something \end{proof} after adding the amsthm package. I got an error!. do you have an idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Section 3.2.2 of the [`ntheorem` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) states, that it is incompatible with `amsthm`. Some of the features of `amsthm` are implemented in `ntheorem` and loading it with `\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}` will emulate them (It will provides the environments `plain`, `defintion`, `remark` and `proof`). **Conclusion:** You can't use `ntheorem` and `amsthm` at once. (I would stick with `ntheorem` instead)

Answer (score 21):

Partial answer that addresses:

- Dropped captital/number is solved by package `lettrine`. It also provides the small caps for `Bezeichnungen:`.
- Color of the number (`gray`).
- Alignment of the equation system (using environment `alignat*` of package `amsmath`. Just for fun I have added additional alignments for `|` and `\in`.
- Letter spacing of the small caps text via `\textls` of package `microtype`.
- As vertical bar `\mid` is used, see also question ["`\mid`, `|` (vertical bar), `\vert`, `\lvert`, `\rvert`, `\divides`"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498/16967).

Also I have enlarged the number a bit for a better aligment with the top of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{theoremgray}{gray}{.5}

\setlength{\textwidth}{.85\textwidth}% just for reproducing the example

\begin{document}
\lettrine[
  loversize=.11,
  findent=0.5em,
  nindent=0pt,
]{\textcolor{theoremgray}{1.1.1}}{\textls{Bezeichnungen:}}
Ist $G$ eine (multiplikativ geschriebene) Gruppe, so f"uhrt man
f"ur beliebige $g \in G$ und $M, N \subseteq G$ die Bezeichnungen
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  &Mg &&= \{mg &&\mid m &&\in M\},\\
  &gN &&= \{gn &&\mid n &&\in N\},\\
  &MN &&= \{mn &&\mid m &&\in M, n \in N\}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Missing:

- Wrapping the visual markup into proper logical markup by defining a theorem style and setting up a theorem, for example.

  The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115424/16967) of Henri Menke shows this using package `ntheorem` as example.

Comment: You should use `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` for _true_ small caps (and better kerning).

Comment: @NauC Thanks for the hint. Also interesting: ["Different small-caps in mathpazo and tgpagella - which are better?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61528/16967)

Comment: How can I obtain letterspacing for the small caps similar to the example picture by OP?

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, missed that. Answer updated with using `\textls` of package `microtype` for letter spacing.

Comment: alignment of the equations is not simply `align*` from `amsmath` -- the original example shows the left-hand side aligned flush left.  can probably be done with `alignat*` but i haven't tried.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, just for fun I have added additional alignments.

Comment: I am not so sure about what the OP is really asking. It seems like OP wants to automate the creation of theorem-like environments with drop cap numbers.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Yes, this is missing, see my answer below "Missing:".

Comment: addition of alignment of `|` closes up the spacing more than appropriat.  maybe `\mid` instead of `|`?  (anyhow, nice "drop cap" for the theorem number.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh. I totally *missed* that. Anyhow, I already added my plus +1 earlier. :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, now using `\mid`.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial solution:** the font is loaded with the package `mathpazo`.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the TeX code that you are using?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, sorry, I deleted the file. But you just need to load the package with `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: Could you then please reproduce the file and upload the code?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, do you want the code for the 3 equations? You can copy it from Heiko's answer below http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115323/14757.