# Using mathpazo with sc but still have small caps for bold titles using tgpagella?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec, small-caps, mathpazo

I have found this [link to code to get this working but doesn't work for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61528/different-small-caps-in-mathpazo-and-tgpagella-which-are-better). I still don't get bold small caps even with switching the font like done in the example. Is there anyway to keep the sc option but get it to use another font in the titles?

I will list the code here as well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\linespread{1.05}

\begin{document}

% here you can see the difference of the two small-cap types
An arbitrary \fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont \textsc{Acronym} and some text. \par
An arbitrary \fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont \textsc{Acronym} and some text. \par
\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont \textsc{Acronym}
\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont \textsc{Acronym}

% my work-around with 'qpl' for titles and 'pplx' for normal text
\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont
\section{Arbitrary \textsc{Acronym}}
\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont
An arbitrary \textsc{Acronym} and some text. \par

\end{document}
```

I've also found this code but that works fine but doesn't reduce the size of the small caps after the first letter. If I manually adjust it using `\scalefont` the letters become to skinny so I would just need to adjust the height of the font but not the width. I don't think this is possible?:

```
\makeatletter
\def\boldseriesname{bx}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mytextsc}[1]{%
    \ifx\f@series\boldseriesname\uppercase{#1}%
    \else{\scshape #1}%
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: When I compile the test code, the word "Acronym" in the section title is bolded.  Is that the issue you are having (not being bolded when you compile)?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It is supposed to be in small caps and bolded. It is bolded but not in small caps.

Comment: For me, the word `Acronym` in the section header is both bolded and small caps.  Thus, it might seem like the issue is with your installation, rather than a LaTeX issue, per se.

Comment: There is no bold small caps font in `mathpazo`, while there is with `tgpagella`. If you need that, you'll have to use `tgpagella`; sure, it's slightly different, but using one version for medium weight and a different one for boldface is surely the last thing I'd try.