# What LGR-encoded Greek fonts are available?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, babel, greek

How many and what are the Greek fonts used (without using `fontspec`) with `pdflatex` + option `italian` babel?

For example, I use `greek.ancient` typing with the latin charaters. See this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Dal greco\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
br\'aqistos
\end{otherlanguage*}(brachistos), e\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
qr\'onos
\end{otherlanguage*}(chronos), tempo. 
\end{document}
```

Please, is it possible to have a *full list* to type in greek font, as from my MWE, but not in math-mode, to put into `<....>`, or into `\usepackage[<....>,italian]{babel}`?

Comment: @Raaja Dear Raaja, your link and your request for closure is absolutely not compatible with my request.

Comment: sorry, retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Raaja Don't worry about it. I make mistakes so many times a day.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David has listed quite a few possibilities. Here I want to highlight two that I find particularly interesting.

## Gentium

[Gentium](https://software.sil.org/gentium/) is an award winning font that supports a wide array of Latin scripts as well as Greek an Cyrillic. You can use it with:

```
\usepackage{gentium}
```

[image]

Note that I had to use "c" instead of "s" to get the correct final sigma (thanks to @Thérèse for spotting this).

## GFS Didot

[GFS Didot](https://greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/_assets/specimens/GFS_Didot_Specimen.pdf) is a free and faithful digital version of Didot's Greek, a.k.a. "apla". GFS has paired the Greek glyphs with Palatino like Latin glyphs, which I do not particularly like. I like the combination with Palatino, though:

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{udidot}
\linespread{1.05}
```

[image]

The `sc` option can be replaced with `osf` to get old-style/lining figures. Some might claim that Pagella is the better choice for Palatino, but [I have preferences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385262/140850).

## Times

In the comments you mention, that you are using `newtxtext`, i.e. Times, as text font and that you like GFS Didot. Unfortunately, GFS Didot is to dark compared to Times, but you can try other fonts, e.g.

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{txr}
```

[image]

Here the Times plus GFS Didot combination, that I do not recommend, with full example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{udidot}
\begin{document}
Dal greco\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
br\'aqistos
\end{otherlanguage*}(brachistos), e\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
qr\'onos
\end{otherlanguage*}(chronos), tempo.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the meantime, I really thank you for your help. I use newtxtext and other mathematical packages as text: example mtpro2 v. lite. I like the second example very much, but for me it is important not to change both the mathematical font and the text font.

Comment: With Gentium, you need to use `c` rather than `s` for final sigma.  Not sure why that’s not the case for your second example.

Comment: @Thérèse thanks for spotting this. This might be a bug in the LGR-metrics for Gentium.

Comment: @Sebastiano See the update if you want to stick with a Times-like font.

Comment: @RalfStubner From what I see, changing text fonts also changes the Greek character. GFS Didot was more beautiful :-). But can't I have the combination GFS Didot+newtxtext? +1 upvoted before.

Comment: @Sebastiano You can combine `newtxtext` with GFS Didot (just write `udidot` instead of `txr` in the last example). However, I don't think this combination works very well when the fonts a combined on a single line, since GFS Didot is noticeably darker. You can try other fonts instead of `txr`, though. For example, `artemisia` looks quite nice.

Comment: @RalfStubner Can you post an example,please? `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{udidot}
\begin{document}
Dal greco\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
br\'aqistos
\end{otherlanguage*}(brachistos), e\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
qr\'onos
\end{otherlanguage*}(chronos), tempo. 
\end{document}` not works.LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `LGR' unknown. [\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{udidot}].Can you put a list complete, please, where I can to change {...}?

Comment: @Sebastiano See the update for a full example. I used your code and added some packages to change fonts ...

Comment: @RalfStubner I have seen :-) thk you very very much. Accepted your answer.

Comment: Note that you can also enter Greek letters in UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ find /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist -name lgr\*fd | wc -l
42
```

so there are 42 font families in texlive 2019 already set up for Greek LGR encoding. If you include use of tools such as ofttotfm than would let you convert otf fonts to an LGR encoded subset there will be hundreds if not thousands of available fonts.

The list from running `find` is

```
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmro.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmss.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmtt.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrlcmss.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrlcmtt.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrlmr.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrlmro.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrlmss.fd
./tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrlmtt.fd
./tex/latex/cm-lgc/lgrfcm.fd
./tex/latex/cm-lgc/lgrfcs.fd
./tex/latex/cm-lgc/lgrfct.fd
./tex/latex/comfortaa/lgrfco.fd
./tex/latex/droid/lgrfdm.fd
./tex/latex/droid/lgrfdr.fd
./tex/latex/droid/lgrfds.fd
./tex/latex/epigrafica/lgrepigrafica.fd
./tex/latex/gentium-tug/lgrgentium.fd
./tex/latex/gfsartemisia/lgrartemisia.fd
./tex/latex/gfsartemisia/lgrartemisiaeuler.fd
./tex/latex/gfsbaskerville/lgrgfsbaskerville.fd
./tex/latex/gfsbodoni/lgrbodoni.fd
./tex/latex/gfscomplutum/lgrcomplutum.fd
./tex/latex/gfsdidot/lgrudidot.fd
./tex/latex/gfsneohellenic/lgrneohellenic.fd
./tex/latex/gfsporson/lgrporson.fd
./tex/latex/gfssolomos/lgrsolomos.fd
./tex/latex/kerkis/lgrkfn.fd
./tex/latex/kerkis/lgrmak.fd
./tex/latex/kerkis/lgrmaksf.fd
./tex/latex/lxfonts/lgrllcmss.fd
./tex/latex/lxfonts/lgrllcmtt.fd
./tex/latex/miama/lgrfmm.fd
./tex/latex/opensans/lgrfos.fd
./tex/latex/opensans/lgrfosj.fd
./tex/latex/tempora/lgrtempora-tlf.fd
./tex/latex/tempora/lgrtempora-tosf.fd
./tex/latex/txfontsb/lgrtxr.fd
./tex/latex/txfontsb/lgrtxrc.fd
./tex/latex/txfontsb/lgrtxry.fd
./tex/latex/txfontsb/lgrtxryc.fd
```

Comment: David, excuse me, but I use MikTeX with a old OS Windows 7 32-bit. I'm unprepared for your answer, which I vote in positive.

Comment: @Sebastiano nothing in this answer is system specific, well miktex may have a slightly different set of available packages but that is unlikely.

Comment: Now I have understood your answer through the answer given by the user. You have entered a list that uses all Greek characters. Either you install them separately, i.e. they are not included in the LaTeX distribution, or some uses fontspec. I should see them one by one if I like them and I should also learn how to use them.

Comment: @Sebastiano no none of them require luatex/xetex/fontspec they are LGR fd files for the 8 bit font encoding for pdflatex so they are all existing  latex font support  in texlive (and most likely in miktex) already,

Comment: Excuse me very much. I'm not an expert. I'm sorry. Could you insert an example to understand how to use these LGR fd files? I don't even know what they are and as they work :-(. In my answer I added artemisia and porson. From your list how can I try the others one by one? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano you use them yourself, in your example you load LGR artemisia `\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}`  that works because `./tex/latex/gfsartemisia/lgrartemisia.fd`  exists in your system, so that list is a list of other fonts you can try.

Comment: Now I understand everything! Thank you with all my heart.

Comment: Unfortunately not everyting that claims to implement LGR does implement the full set of LGR glyphs, so one needs to check the output if one wants to typeset ploytonic greek

Answer (score 2):

At the answer of the user @RalfStubner and best user @David Carlisle I add:

### porson (greek)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{porson}
\begin{document}
Dal greco\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
br\'aqistos
\end{otherlanguage*}(brachistos), e\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
qr\'onos
\end{otherlanguage*}(chronos), tempo.
\end{document}
```

### Artemisia

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}%%%%% You must delete from %%%lgrartemisia.fd, lgr to have only artemisia. Same for every font of the list of %%%@David Carlisle.
\begin{document}
Dal greco\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
br\'aqistos
\end{otherlanguage*}(brachistos), e\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
qr\'onos
\end{otherlanguage*}(chronos), tempo.
\end{document}
```

If there are others I can add, I am glad you can edit my answer. Greetings and thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2):

The list of [Greek fonts on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-greek) is a good resource.  Not all of them are Type 1 fonts in the LGR encoding, which is what you are looking for, but the links there will take you to the documentation of each.

At a glance, the usable options appear to be: the GFS fonts, Kerkis (a companion for Bookman/TeX Gyre Schola), Tempora or txfontsb (companions for Times), Cochineal, Gentium, DejaVu, Libertine and Miama.  Several are extensions of Computer Modern, but you would get those by switching to `cmr`.

By some oversight, [lxfonts](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lxfonts/doc/LXfonts-demo.pdf) and [opensans](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/opensans/doc/fonts/opensans/opensans.pdf) are not in the list of Greek fonts even though both come in LGR.  Neither is likely to be usable for you: lxfonts is intended for slides, and Open Sans supports only monotonic Greek.

Epigraphica looked promising (as an extension of Optima/URW Classico), but seems to have been abandoned in 2007 without ever including polytonic support.  I would try Lingua Franca instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and suggestions: +1.