# Xelatex and mathpazo font

Tags: fonts, xetex

I tried to compile this code using xelatex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It seems the font is not loading.
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should not combine `fontspec` with packages like `mathpazo`. see the [linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504366/140850) for possibilities to use Palatino (like) fonts for text and math.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the proper way to do it, but it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{arabxetex} %thanks to this guy
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{equation}
f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. You are resetting the encoding to something that doesn't work with xetex. Try some words with non-ascii char. E.g. `Straße`.

Answer (score 0):

`mathpazo` package mainly designed for `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF` or `PDFLaTeX`, its
better to use the packages `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` to get Palatino by using `xeLaTeX`, and the codes are:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}

This is for test
\[
a+b=c1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe that works, but it doesn't answer the question how to use `mathpazo`. -1

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry, I've updated my suggestion...

Comment: That doesn't work either with xelatex. Try to type `Straße`.