# Roman numerals in TOC are not in smallcaps - microtype problem with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, small-caps, microtype, roman-numerals

I'm using the **memoir** class for typesetting a book. In the `\frontmatter` I have a chapter with a section and a subsection.

My problem is that, in the TOC, the page number of the chapter appears in lowercase, and I would like it to be in smallcaps (as they appear in the section and subsection):

[image]

Even stranger, when I tried an MWE, the problem didn't appear:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\usepackage{eulervm} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\chapterstyle{dash}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\settocdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents* 

\chapter{A modo de introducción}    
\section{Convenciones}    
\subsection{Números de línea}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Cecilia Payne, PhD.}
\chapter{Antonia Maury, Aydte.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit:

I think I found the package responsible for the behaviour: `microtype`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\usepackage{eulervm} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{microtype} % <--- This is the problem

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents* 

\chapter{A modo de introducción}
\section{Convenciones}
\subsection{Números de línea}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Cecilia Payne, PhD.}
\chapter{Antonia Maury, Aydte.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the **xi** appear as **XI**.

### Edit 2:

After the wonderful answer and insight of Iacobus1983, I think that the problem is far out of reach. So I think that I will get the chapter titles *and* numbers in small caps:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\usepackage{eulervm} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\settocdepth{subsection}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\scshape}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage \tableofcontents* 

\chapter{A modo de introducción}

\section{Convenciones}

\subsection{Números de línea}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Cecilia Payne, PhD.}
\section{Una sección}
\subsection{Una subsección}

\chapter{Antonia Maury, Aydte.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It doesn't look bad. ;)

Comment: Do you mean lower case (not small caps)? I.e. would you like to have xii instead of XII? Not knowing your code, have you tried using `roman` instead of `Roman` where appropriate?

Comment: @Ingmar : I would like to have XI instead of xi. By the way, thank you for the edition! I haven't use `roman` nor `Roman`...

Comment: This is not `memoir` related, also happens with `book`. Note that it is very well known that spanish babel messes with roman and and thus may confuse other  packages.

Comment: @daleif : Thank you for your comment; I will edit the tags then.

Comment: My guess is that microtype needs some sort of "definition" of smallcaps and does not found them for mathpazo font. I mean, if I comment `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` I see smallcaps even with microtype. EDIT: also removing the `sc` option does work. So, microtype has a problem with this `sc`option for true smallcaps.

Comment: @Iacobus1983 : You are right! Thank you! But I like mathpazo and its `sc` option... would it be possible to solve?

Comment: @LuisLopez: Sorry, I had just posted an answer (saying that you can compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) but I realised a minute later that the font was not kept... For a fix with pdfLaTeX I'm not competent enough. Possibly there is a otf equivalent of mathpazo, in this case you could use XeLaTeX + fontspec.

Comment: @LuisLópez : see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504366/how-to-use-palatino-font-for-text-and-what-about-maths

Comment: see here: https://github.com/jbezos/babel-spanish/issues/10

Comment: Thanks, Robert! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the issue happens only in the Table of contents (not in other small caps text within the document), you can (with memoir) just add `\scshape` in the page number font, so:

`\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\scshape}`

If I add this to your preamble I get this (I've added a section and a subsection to ensure that everything is ok):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but I would like the page numbers of the chapters to be in bold face. I tried both `\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\scshape\bfseries}` and `\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\bfseries\scshape}`, but neither works...

Comment: @LuisLópez : I'm sorry. By the way, I see that `\scshape\bfseries` (or the equivalent `\textsc{\textbf{foo}`) does not work also outside the table of contents, and also without `microtype`. So, I suspect that mathpazo has no support for bold small caps... But I'm no great expert, I hope someone else finds a solution.

Comment: I add something: without `microtype` the smallcaps+bf seems to work in the toc but not elsewhere (a bit puzzling), and the compilers issues the warning: "Package spanish Warning: Replacing `T1/pplx/b/sc' by faked small caps on input line 2."

Comment: Please don't mind! Your answer is really useful (I will check it now :)). I see that the problem is really deep...